# Long Debate of mantaining session in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, session

I have seen many question that states what pros and cons of saving session in db or mem cache.
stil both have issues, mem-cache is not persistent and if you save session in DB that could be performance issue .(retrieving info from db is tedious task ). What if I have an app like facebook what should be my preference?

2-This is the schema if I use DB option but how that would help me considering my user can log in from any location using different IP address.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'ci_sessions' (
  session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  user_data text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

3- Last but not the least how the big giants like Facebook, Google saves users data?

4-Any PHP Library that could help in Management other than tradition session handling.
If not that would be a hot opportunity for me to work on.

Comment: Personally, I use redis, with load-balanced redis servers and using persistence

Comment: @MarkBaker does that work? you mean NOSQL approach?

Comment: It works well; I don't need to use sticky sessions because the redis servers are available across all my webheads; if I loose any of the redis servers, the others will take up the slack and replication means they all have access to all sessions (there might be a minimal time between updating a session and its replication, but I haven't had any problems with it); and even if I lose the redis cluster, persistence means that when I recover it the session data will still be there

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks I know very less about redis and just googled that, considering my site is hosted on AWS with PHP and mysql as the Database , I can still benifit redis? just wondering how to get started?

Comment: AWS Elasticache offers redis as an alternative option to memcache.... it doesn't support multiple redis servers in the cache cluster yet (though I believe it's planned for later this year)... I've done some deployments using it, and while it's still a SPoF it's a stable one (and those deployments were going from an environment where the entire apps were SPoF) so it was still an overall win... and I've had no problems with its stability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get benefits of memory cache speed with the option to backup in near real time to persistant store, try using REDIS:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/saving-php-sessions-in-redis/
- [How safe it is to store session with Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278683/how-safe-it-is-to-store-session-with-redis)

You can use a DB like MySQL as the persistent store and have REDIS backup every second or so...

Some links to help out:

- http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html
- http://redis.io/topics/persistence
- http://www.slideshare.net/jimbojsb/scaling-php-applications-with-redis

Comment: but still what could be the possible schema for storing in DB.

Comment: @user1765876 here is a good slide show that can walk you through it http://www.slideshare.net/jimbojsb/scaling-php-applications-with-redis

Comment: as mentioned in this link http://www.sitepoint.com/saving-php-sessions-in-redis/ I read how to make session on Redis, but just want to know, after we configure this as mentioned in this article does $_SESSION['abc']=12; will be creating session on redis?

Comment: @user1765876 yes if you've constructed your session handlers (http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) to create, read, save, etc...  via REDIS and registered them (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) $_SESSION['abc']=12; will work just as if you used the default file handler.

Comment: the data will be saved on Redis instance?

Comment: instead of file it will be saved in Redis right?