# Is it wrong to use sessions in Microservices?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, spring-session

I have read that, session is against the concept of RESTfulness.

[Do sessions really violate RESTfulness?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6068113/1358676)

[Session Management in microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741333/session-management-in-microservices/32743085#32743085)

[RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)

Since Microservices inevitably use `REST`, does the same apply here as well? If so, then why do we have Spring session? It even lists 'Spring Session allows providing session ids in headers to work with `RESTful` APIs' as one of its features.

Comment: This is going to be primarily opinion-based, but I don't have a problem with sessions as long as the sessions aren't part of the server's local state (e.g., you use Spring Session with Redis).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apart from **Scaling** as an advantage of micro-services, it also provides you with the flexibility to choose polyglot architecture i.e (using the right programming language, framework, database for the right job).

If you use spring sessions(which off-course provides session replication across nodes), internally it uses Redis/gemfire/hazelcast as a replicated session store, but you will have to stick to one programming language & framework for all your services i.e Java & Spring resp.(You can off course write your own implementation in other languages to read from session store, but its re-inventing the wheels) And this will take away Benefit of Polyglot Architecture.

So typically in microservices architecture, you have a token-service(and it should be able to scale individually) implementation to generate tokens(aka sessionIds) which are used for Authentication & Authorization in each service and you should try to avoid storing the session information. It will also help to avoid "**Single point of Failure**".

Comment: How to whitelist/blacklist some users without waiting expiration time? Can it be stateless?